# Android ListView stops scrolling when inside a Scroll View

Tags: android

Why is it when I insert a list view into a scrollview, the list view stops scrolling.
The Scroll View scrolls normally, but the list view seems as if it is frozem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that you must not place a list view inside a scroll view, because the system will not know which control to scroll!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add listview in scrollview since scrolling is a default property for

ListView. That is all.

Please go through the Android documentation before design any of the UI.

Comment: What I have is a form for sending emails, the form is composed of a list view containing image attachments, and three text entries, The last text entry being blocked by the soft key board when it gets focus, so i put the whole form inside a Scroll view, so that the form will automatically scroll to make room for the soft key board, That's why i needed to put the list view inside a scroll view, ;) Regards